# Reset Ehcache in a thread safe way

Tags: java, multithreading, ehcache

I use Ehcache in my project and I have a helper class:

```
public static void reset(Ehcache cache, List<MyClass> list) {
    List<Element> elementList = new ArrayList<Element>(list.size());
    for (MyClass myClass : list) {
        elementList.add(new Element(myClass.getId(), myClass));
    }
    // missing write lock
    cache.removeAll();
    // if findByKey(...) executed at this time, it's result will be null
    cache.putAll(elementList);
}

public static MyClass findByKey(Ehcache cache, Serializable key) {...
public static List<MyClass> findAll(Ehcache cache) {...
public static MyClass findFirstByQuery(Ehcache cache, Criteria criteria) {...
public static List<MyClass> findByQuery(Ehcache cache, Criteria criteria) {...
public static void put(Ehcache cache, MyClass myClass) {...
```

I need to synchronize the methods. Do I have to implement it manually in all methods or is there any other (Ehcache specific) way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on your own here in the sense that Ehcache does not offer an out-of-the-box solution for this.

You also need to realize that depending on the frequency and running time of that update, this may cause bottle necks. 
Can't you find a different pattern for doing this?

Comment: It seems I have to! :) Thanks!